# How to force "full range" flag on export

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg command to remap audio tracks to discrete channels in a ProRes 4444 quicktime file. Even if the input video is copied to the output, the exported file is interpreted by a professional video player software as video range (16-234 values) instead of the original full range (0-255 values), making it look more contrasted.

The content is actually correct, changing manually the range setting in the player software gives back the right light range, so I think the output file just lose some kind of range flag.

I already tried the following options without results:

- ```
  -colorspace bt709 -movflags +write_colr
  ```
- ```
  -dst_range 1 -color_range 2
  ```
- ```
  -vf scale=out_range=full
  ```
- ```
  -vf scale=in_range=full:out_range=full
  ```

Original command is:

```
ffmpeg -i F:\_IMPORT\TST_ProRes4444_4k.mov -map 0:0 -c copy -map 0:1 -c copy -map_channel 0.2.0:0.2 -c:a pcm_s24le F:\_EXPORT\TEST\test.mov
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The Quicktime MOV format does not support signaling color range.

> The remaining component values that fall outside the mapping for
>   scheme B (1 to 15 and 241 to 254 for n = 8 bits and 4 to 63 and 961 to
>   1019 for n = 10 bits) accommodate occasional filter undershoot and
>   overshoot in image processing. In some applications, these values are
>   used to carry other information (e.g., transparency). The writer of a
>   QuickTime image may use these values and the reader of a QuickTime
>   image must expect these values.

from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-143693

Also see https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org/msg19491.html

Comment: Interesting informations, thank you. Sadly it doesn't explain why the original file is working as intended and why copying its essence makes it change.

Comment: Likely the original file is using some non-standard form of signaling. Which app generated it?

Comment: It's generated by R&S Clipster, an high end hardware/software system for digital cinema mastering.

Comment: And does ffplay play the input and output with the same rendering?

Comment: Yes with ffplay they look the same. I think it's because video data IS the same. Our problem is to know why Clipster automatically reads the input clip as FULL and the output clip as VIDEO (and apparently the client's software does too :D)

Comment: Can you share a short file?

Comment: I cannot share the actual file, I'll prepare a test one tomorrow. Thank you again for your help ;)

Comment: I shared the input and output files here: http://217.194.3.37/owncloud/index.php/s/kXCQec99MONhjnk

Comment: The input and output sample are both detected as studio range by ffmpeg. The input has a `Rnge` child box in `stsd` which looks to be the culprit. I don't see that box mentioned in the Quicktime File Format spec, so it's bespoke.

Comment: How can I check stsd and the Rnge child box? I'm not at this knowledge level about encoders, must learn.

Comment: Use a box dumping tool like movdump from [bmx](https://sourceforge.net/p/bmxlib/home/Home/) to check boxes.